# Capistrano + Nginx + Passenger = 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I have spent the last few days trying to solve this problem, and I'm just not making any headway. I actually just created a stackoverflow account specifically to ask this question. It seems that this issue is pretty common, but none of the solutions I found solve the problem for me.

Yesterday I came across this tutorial: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/a-guide-to-a-nginx-passenger-and-rvm-server

I had hoped started from scratch using this tutorial would work, but no dice. Either way, if you view the tutorial you can see what steps I have taken.

Here is essentially what I have going on.

1. I have a VPS account on linode.com
2. Server OS is **Ubuntu 10.04**
3. Local OS (shouldn't matter, but just so you know) used to deploy with Capistrano is Snow Leopard 10.6.6
4. I use **RVM** on the server. **Version is 1.2.2**
5. I was previously on ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ], but per the tutorial listed above I switched to **ree-1.8.7-2010.02 [ i386 ]**.
6. Running '**which ruby**' from the command line verifies that I am using 1.8.7 with the following output: **/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby**
7. **passenger -v** prints the following: **Phusion Passenger version 3.0.2**
8. I'm not sure how to tell what my nginx version is, but it should be the most recent one as I installed it yesterday via the passenger installer commands listed in the tutorial above.
9. I have **two users** dealing with the install. **root** which I used to install everything, and **deployer** which is a user I created specifically to for deploying my applications
10. My web app directory is in the deployer user's home directory as follows: **/home/deployer/webapps/mysite.com/public**
11. Per Capistrano default deploy, a **symbolic link called current** is created in the public folder, and **points to /home/deployer/webapps/mysite.com/public/releases/most_current_release**
12. I have chmodded the deployer directory recursively to 777
13. **/opt/nginx** permissions: **rwxr-xr-x**
14. **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/passenger-3.0.2** permissions: **rwxrwsrwx**
15. My nginx config file has gone through just short of eternity variations, but currently looks like this:

==================================================================================

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/bin/passenger_ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
       # listen      *:80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        root   /home/deployer/webapps/mysite.com/public/current;

        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_friendly_error_pages on;


        access_log logs/mysite.com/server.log;
        error_log logs/mysite.com/error.log info;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

==================================================================================

I bounce nginx, hit the site, and boom. 403, and logs say **directory index of /home/deployer... is forbidden**

As others with a similar problem have said, you can drop an index.html into the public/releases/current_release and it will render. But rails no worky.

That's basically it. At this point I have just about completely exhausted every possible solution attempt I can think of. I am a programmer and definitely not a sysadmin, so I am 99% sure this has something to do with permissions that I have hosed, but for the life of me I just can't figure out where.

If anyone can help I would really really appreciate it. If there's any specific permission things you want me to check (ie groups/permissions), can you please include the commands to do so as well. Hopefully this will help others in the future who read this post.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide, and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Anyone? I'm so stuck. Close to completely bailing on nginx. Help? Please?

Answer (score 1):

reverse public and current for the root directive.

root   /home/deployer/webapps/mysite.com/current/public;

Answer (score 1):

You should add deployer user and root to rvm group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G rvm deployer
sudo usermod -a -G rvm root
```

Answer (score 0):

'nginx -v' outputs the version (or, client-side, view headers in your browser).

Slicehost has excellent articles for this sort of thing that you might compare with your own configuration, or even follow from the beginning. [I use Linode too but prefer Slicehost's tutorials. ;)]

http://articles.slicehost.com/tags/nginx

The nginx tutorials definitely cover permission settings, which sounds like the cause of the problem you're describing.

They also have articles covering Rails and Capistrano.

Comment: OK that may be part of my problem. I tried running 'nginx -v' and received this: -bash: nginx: command not found. I thought there was another way to do it, but now that you say this is right, maybe this points to something else? I'll dig through those articles again, but honestly I've ready pretty much everything out there. Thanks for your help.